# Sending image via whatsapp api using c#

Tags: c#, image, api, send, whatsapp

hello i'm trying to send an image using c#

but the image not delivered and there is no exception message !!!

here's my code

```
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("e:\\img.gif");
    wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connected to whatsapp...");

        wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
        {
            wa.SendMessage(to, msg);

            wa.SendMessageImage(to,img,ApiBase.ImageType.GIF);
            MessageBox.Show("Message Sent...");
        };
 }
```

Comment: What library are you using for this? And since `whatsapp` deliberately does not release an API, and is actively against people who have reverse-engineered it, I suspect it may be because the API has changed, but the library has not. You would have better luck posting on their forums or digging through the source code.

Comment: @Rob i'm using Chat-API-.NET API , and this method work for many people and still , but with me have a problem :3

Comment: The events are success events. Have you hooked up the failure events as well? The code may not throw exceptions, but might relay information through events instead? Also... Where is the code to login after connecting? If it's before all this.. it's possible that Login completes before you hook up the event listener, because you popup a message box..

Answer (score 2):

I too was facing the same problem, fortunately I got the solution :)

```
byte[] img = File.ReadAllBytes("e:\\img.gif");
wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
{
      MessageBox.Show("Connected to whatsapp...");

      wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
      {
          wa.SendMessage(to, msg);

          wa.SendMessageImage(to + "@s.whatsapp.net",img,ApiBase.ImageType.GIF);
          MessageBox.Show("Message Sent...");
      };
}
```

You will just need to modify only 1 line in your code.

```
wa.SendMessageImage(to + "@s.whatsapp.net",img,ApiBase.ImageType.GIF);
```

Hop this will help others too :D
Hav a Nyc day :)